# Datanucleus JDO + MySQL create longtext column

Tags: mysql, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to use DataNucleus's JDO in my own Java project (not GAE), and i need to store quite long pieces of text in my DB.

I am using Eclipse to do all the dirty work, like enhancing and creating the schema, but unfortunately, all `String` ivars are mapped to `VARCHAR` columns. But how do i get Datanucleus to create a `LONGTEXT` column for me?

I also tried the `@Colunn` annotation, but i still got the `VARCHAR`.

`@Persistent
    @Column(name="COMPONENT", jdbcType="LONGVARCHAR", length=1000000)
    private String component;`

I also tried specifying `LONGTEXT` as `jdbcType`, but the Schematool informed me, that that datatype could not be used.

Thank you in advance, 
Happy New Year, 
Best regards,
Timofey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LONGTEXT is not a **JDBC** type. They are all clearly listed in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html

The DataNucleus log tells you what JDBC types are available **for that JDBC driver** (since it provides that information to the utilising software). It chooses to map JDBC type LONGVARCHAR onto "LONG VARCHAR" IIRC (easily visible by using SchemaTool "dbinfo"). You could obviously generate the schema into a text file and update it yourself before applying it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As to generating the schema into a file and then editing it before applying it, i'd really like everything "just to happen", without my interaction. As far as i understood, there is no way of telling DataNucleus to use the LONGTEXT type, is there? But could i use a specific Java type (like google's Text) or write my own that would map specifically to LONGTEXT?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Persistent
@Column(name="COMPONENT", jdbcType="CLOB")
private String component;
```

The data type CLOB maps to medium text. But once the database is created you can change it to LONGTEXT